# Hotkeys (COMMAND-V ....) don't honor Dvorak layout

Tags: keyboard

I'm on 10.9 Mavericks and I am using the Dvorak keyboard layout. However every time I go to paste something using the COMMAND-V shortcut it doesn't do anything, I discovered hitting the physical V key which is K on Dvorak it works. What's going on here? The shortcut keys seem to honor QWERTY layout instead of Dvorak, I don't even have QWERTY enabled as a selection on my account, the system-wide default is Dvorak. How can I fix this? It's really annoying.

Comment: This is the way the basic short-cuts were originally designed.  They are not ZXCV, but instead they are the first 4 keys from the left on the bottom row.  This "first four keys" rule is still the default for other keyboard layouts.  This also explains the strange choice of *V* for paste and *Z* for undo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using "Dvorak - Qwerty ⌘".

How to fix:

1. Open "System Preferences" > "Keyboard" > "Input Source".
2. Click "+" and select "Dvorak".
3. Select "Dvorak - Qwerty ⌘" and click "−".