# Shortcuts stopped to work when Dvorak + macOS BigSur 11.4

Tags: macos, keyboard, dvorak

I upgraded my macOS and after it the shortcuts stopped to work, on all apps!

It's like the Command + N is not respecting the current selected keyboard layout, it's using the QWERTY layout for the shortcuts.

I have been using Dvorak layout more than 8 years, and it's the first time that this is happening. I am not sure if it was because of the update or not.

Anyone know how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here][1].

[Hotkeys (COMMAND-V ....) don't honor Dvorak layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193409/hotkeys-command-v-dont-honor-dvorak-layout)

The weird is that I always used the `Dvorak - QWERTY` layout, and only now this behaviour started. Anyway, I changed to only `Dvorak` and now it's fixed.